# TemplateNotFound in Airflow

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I have the following dir structure

```
.
├── ConfigSpark.yaml
├── project1
│   ├── dags
│   │   └── dag_1.py
│   └── sparkjob
│       └── spark_1.py
└── sparkutils
```

I'm trying to import de `ConfigSpark.yaml` file in my `SparkKubernetesOperator` using:

```
job= SparkKubernetesOperator(
            task_id = 'job',
            params=dict(
                app_name='job',
                mainApplicationFile='/opt/airflow/dags/project1/sparkjob/spark_1.py',
                driverCores=1,
                driverCoreRequest='250m',
                driverCoreLimit='500m',
                driverMemory='2G',
                executorInstances=1,
                executorCores=2,
                executorCoreRequest='1000m',
                executorCoreLimit='1000m',
                executorMemory='2G'
            ),
            application_file='/opt/airflow/dags/ConfigSpark.yaml',
            kubernetes_conn_id='conn_prd_eks',
            do_xcom_push=True
    )
```

My dag is returning the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /opt/airflow/dags/ConfigSpark.yaml
```

I've noticed that if the DAG is in the same directory of ConfigSpark.yaml my tasks run perfectly, but why my task is not running when I place my dag in a subfolder?

I've checked my `values.yaml` file and `airflowHome` is `/opt/airflow` and `defaultAirflowRepository` is `apache/airflow`.

What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airflow searches for the template file (`ConfigSpark.yaml` in your case) from the directory in which the DAG file is stored. Therefore, it doesn't find it automatically with your code.

If you would store the template file in same folder your DAG file is stored in (`/project1/dags`), or a nested folder inside the `/project1/dags` folder, you can specify the path from there in your task:

```py
job = SparkKubernetesOperator(
    ...,
    application_file='/path/to/ConfigSpark.yaml',
    ...
)
```

Which would read the template file from `/project1/dags/path/to/ConfigSpark.yaml`.

However, if the folder your template file is stored in is not a child of the folder your DAG file is stored in, the above won't work. In that case you can specify `template_searchpath` on the DAG-level:

```py
with DAG(..., template_searchpath="/opt/airflow/dags/repo/dags") as dag:
    job = SparkKubernetesOperator(
        task_id='job',
        application_file='ConfigSpark.yaml',
        ...,
    )
```

This path (for example `/opt/airflow/dags`) is added to the Jinja searchpath and that way `ConfigSpark.yaml` will be found.

Comment: I used `template_searchpath='opt/airflow/dags/repo/dags'` and it worked. Although, when I call my sparkjob using `SparkKubernetesOperator` the same doesn't work. In my `mainApplicationFile` argument I used `/project1/sparkjob/spark_1.py` and I got the following error then `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Spark application failed with state: FAILED`

Comment: I've tried to use `local:///` in `mainApplicationFile` like `local:///project1/sparkjob/spark_1.py` but I got `python3: can't open file '/project1/sparkjob/spark_1.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`